# Can I send Audio messages / notification in Android Auto?

Tags: android, notifications, media, voice, android-auto

Can I just send only Android Text messages as notifications to Android Auto Messaging system/app or -  Is it possible to send media files like a voice/audio/mp3 notification via Android Auto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now audio messages are not supported.(API level 21)
Note that Android auto platform has feature to read out the text sent.
And same way, for the reply, android auto can capture the user voice and return it as text.